# how to load addressbook contacts in blackBerry (storm)

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

I am working on an application in which I need to show all of the address book contacts.
Please give me a code snippet or link which will help me do that.

Answer (score 2):

How To - Access Address Book contacts
Last Updated: 6 February 2009
Article Number: DB-00147
[link](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800363/How_To_-_Access_Address_Book_contacts.html?nodeid=800364&vernum=0)